# how to fix the function to check the same random array value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am learning javascript, I have been able to create a function that has a parameter, the function has the task of forming an array containing a 2 character (0/1) random string of 1 parameter and the return value must be an array.
example:

```
console.log (generateString(2));
```

sample results:

```
['01', '11']
```

The problem I face is even though it's a random string, but it still has the possibility to have the same value. Suppose I run the program code

```
console.log (generateString(4));
```

and one of the results is like this:

```
['00', '00', '01', '10']
```

my question is how can I ensure that the return value of the array has no duplicate value? This is my code so far..

```js
function generateString(num){

        let newArray = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
            let randomChar = generateCharacters();
            if(i >= 1 && (newArray[i - 1] === randomChar)){
                randomChar = generateCharacters();
                newArray.push(randomChar);
            } else {
                newArray.push(randomChar);
            }

        }
        return newArray;
    }

    function generateCharacters(){
        const chars = '01';
        let result = '';
        for (let j = 2; j > 0; --j){
            result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
        }
        return result;
    }

    console.log(generateString(4));
```

Comment: What do you hope to get from `generateString(5)`?

Comment: The test case is just only `generateString(4)`

Comment: For four number its just returning all the permutations of the string. And for less numbers its random numbers from permutations of strings.

Comment: just generate all possible values and return a shuffled array. this has been asked many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for the duplicate before adding the new string.

```html
function generateString(num){

        let newArray = [];
  let i =0;
        while(i<num){
          console.log(newArray)
            let randomChar = generateCharacters();
            if(newArray.indexOf(randomChar)<=-1){
              
                newArray.push(randomChar);
            i+=1;
            }

        }
        return newArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `do-while` inside the `for-loop` and keep making new random strings until the new strings generated is not included in the previous array.

```js
function generateString(num){

        let newArray = [];
        let randomChar;
        for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
            do{
              randomChar = generateCharacters();
            }
            while(newArray.includes(randomChar));
            newArray.push(randomChar)

        }
        return newArray;
    }

    function generateCharacters(){
        const chars = '01';
        let result = '';
        for (let j = 2; j > 0; --j){
            result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
        }
        return result;
    }

    console.log(generateString(4));
```

Comment: In theory the inner `while` loop could have to be executed many times, hurting the time complexity. Of course, with an array of 4 elements that is not relevant. But as soon as you go to let's say 100 elements, the slow-down becomes noticible.

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle the array of all 4 possible pairs of digits:

```js
function shuffle(a) {
    for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        let temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }
    return a;
}

function generateString(num){
    let all = ["00", "01", "10", "11"];
    shuffle(all);
    return all.slice(0, num); // Only take the number of elements requested
}

console.log(generateString(4));
```

Comment: Can I ask why you used reverse loop instead of starting from start?

Comment: @MaheerAli, It makes it easier to get the random index `j`. Otherwise you would have to add an offset to it, as the random index should be in the range of the not-yet-randomised part of the array (see [Fisher-Yates algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) ).

Comment: I got it thaks. However here you could have used a better approach which is to get a random element from array `all` and then remove it and do it `num` times. This will you won't generate extra numbers and one function will do all.

Comment: Removing an element from an array is in theory less efficient as all following elements must be moved. Of course, with a hard-coded array of length 4 that is irrelevant. In the general case however, the Fisher-Yates algorithm gives the best efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Made changes in your `generateString` function. You can use set for not updating duplicates in the result. I think you need to update `generateCharacters` function to generate all possible strings properly.

```js
function generateString(num){
    let newArraySet = new Set();

    for(let i = 0; i < num; i++){
        let randomChar = generateCharacters();
  while(newArraySet.has(randomChar)) {
   randomChar = generateCharacters();
  }
  newArraySet.add(randomChar);
    }
    return Array.from(newArraySet);
}

function generateCharacters(){
    const chars = '01';
    let result = '';
    for (let j = 2; j > 0; --j){
        result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(generateString(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

When building the array you need to check to see if the random number is not already in the array before adding it to the array.  This function will return true if you feed it the array in question and your "random" item you need to check.

```js
function isInArray(myArray, arrayItemToCheck)
{
  var found = myArray.find(function(arrayItem) {
    return arrayItem == arrayItemToCheck;
  });
  return !!found
}
```

in your function, you change the line  `let randomChar = generateCharacters();` to:

```js
let randomChar;
// loops forever until condition is met
while (true) {
    randomChar = generateCharacters();
    if (!isInArray(newArray, randomChar)) {            
        break;
    } 
}
```